# EB: Automatically deploy new Docker image build from Docker Hub

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker

Is it possible to setup a web hook to automatically deploy a new version of an application from a Docker Hub repository to Elastic Beanstalk?

I currently have the following setup:

```
Bitbucket Repo -----> Docker Hub -----> Elastic Beanstalk
```

When I push to the master branch on the git repository, it triggers a build on the Docker repository through a POST request. However, once the image is built, I have to manually deploy it on EB.

Docker Hub has the option for making a POST request whenever a build is successfully completed. Is there some API or URL that I could point Docker to call so that EB redeploys the application?

Note: Eventually I would like to include an automated testing server into this workflow.

Answer (score 1):

AWS does not seem to have a HTTP API, but you can use the aws command-line tool to trigger the update: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41715702/5879759