# Elastic Beanstalk does not update image from ECR automatically

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-ecr

I have 
 "Update": "true" in Dockerrun.aws.json 
which should automatically update the image and container in the EC2 ionstance when i update the image in ECR.

But when i ssh into the instance after pushing a new image , i still see the container and image not updated.

[root@ip-10-20-60-125 ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c8e3bab8da13        258e7bc272bd        "./graphhopper.sh we…"   8 days ago          Up 8 days           8989/tcp            tender_mayer

[root@ip-10-20-60-125 ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
aws_beanstalk/current-app   latest              258e7bc272bd        8 days ago          813MB
openjdk                     8-jdk               b8d3f94869bb        6 weeks ago         625MB

Dockerrun.aws.json has this

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "xxxxx",
    "Key": "xxxxx"
  },

  "Image": {
    "Name": "213074117100.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxx:latest",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8989"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/data",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/data"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/eb",
  "Command": "xxxxx"
}
```

Is there a setting somewhere other than update: "true" ?

If i do a eb deploy, it will pull and update.  But  "Update": "true" should pull and update automatically when i update the image, which is not happening.

Comment: did you end up figuring out what it was? currently experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

From this [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html) and this thread [AWS Beanstalk docker image automatic update doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241428/aws-beanstalk-docker-image-automatic-update-doesnt-work) it seems that update=true just does the `docker pull` before `docker run` and it will not update the container on a new image update.

From my current research, it seems there is no way to automate this process at this moment.